# Ember CLI test intermittently failing

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm having a problem where when running my Ember tests. Once in every 3-5 tries it hits errors before running any tests. When I run in server mode I can see this output:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: EmberENV at http://localhost:7357/3256/tests/index.html?hidepassed, line 42

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: define at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader-53146f185443881bff29aab3e80079e2.js, line 3

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: define at http://localhost:7357/assets/tests-a72d35574ec0d1ab014d4af21210a23a.js, line 1
```

When I look at the offensive files referenced, they looks like this:

```
/* globals requirejs, require */
(function() {
define("ember-cli/test-loader",
  [],
  function() {
    "use strict";

    var moduleIncludeMatchers = [];
    var moduleExcludeMatchers = [];

    function addModuleIncludeMatcher(fn) {
      moduleIncludeMatchers.push(fn);
    };
```

etc...

As I understand, define() is a function introduced by requirejs, so it seems like it's just not loading before the tests begin. Any idea why this would be, and if there is any way to ensure things are loaded in the proper order?

Other important things; this doesn't seem to be an issue with the individual tests, as deleting them, especially the first which would be hit doesn't make a difference. This looks like it started happening occasionally after a big check in, where among other things, we went from 130 to 174 tests, but nothing particularly strange seems to have been introduced. I've also tried cutting out pieces of the new code with no change, BUT if I revert to the previous version it seems to still work correctly every time. It could just be a matter of the codebase growing larger.

For versions of dependencies:

```
EmberCLI: 1.13.13
node: 5.4.1
PhantomJS: 2.1.1
```

Anything else that would be helpful to provide? Thanks.

Comment: I am running into similar errors, now that EmberCLI 2.3.0 we're trying to upgrade to that. Any luck solving this?

EmberCLI 2.3.0
Node: 4.2.6
PhantomJS: 2.1.1

Strangely, the errors don't seem to happen on local Mac OS X development machines, but do occur in CI and in our Docker test environment.

Comment: any luck solving this?

Comment: Nothing concrete yet, though it seems to be happening less now without any related changes of which I can think. I'm exploring Jon's suggestion below.

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to report back here that it has been fixed in my case. 
First of all this issue was reported here: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14173, and it's likely caused by some inline import `@import url(...)` used in css.

The fix in my case is to write an alternative test runner which ignore the network request, similar to what `@wagenet` suggested in the above issue.

Hopefully that works for other use cases.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and were able to fix it by updating qunit to 1.20.0 in bower.json

```
"qunit": "~1.20.0",
```

Comment: I already have that version of qunit defined in my bower.json, however we also use npm and in my package.json we had it defined as ^1.0.4 where 1.2.4 is now the newest. I'm not sure which one is being used during tests, but I'm upgrading the ^1.2.4 in my package.json and seeing if it helps.

Comment: Nah no luck with this, still failing occasionally. Good thought though, and I imagine the answer is changing the versions of some related dependency.

Comment: If you want to share your bower and package dependancies, I can check to see if we have anything similar with a different version?

Comment: @TwoLeggedMammal Have you fixed this problem? I am currently seeing the same issue on jenkins build. I am on Ember 2.4, Phantom 2.1.7.

Comment: @zhujy_8833 nah we never did. It's only failing about half the time now, and we use Ember for very little so we're gotten by through just rerunning when it fails.